# Change of a database design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have a problem with the design of some tables of my database. The problem is:

I have 2 tables:

```
Level
   Id (PK)
   Name

Union
   Id (PK)
   LevelId (FK)
   CityId (FK)
   PostalCodeId (FK)
   CountryId (FK)
```

Actually, I have 3 Levels, with Id 1, 2 and 3 respectively. And in the union table, I can have only 1 FK marks with 1 level. For example, Level with Id 1 is always associate with a City, so the field LevelId will be filled with 1 and CityId will be filled with its corresponding identifier (the other fields will be null). LevelId 2 with PostalCodeId (the other fields will be null) and LevelId 3 with CountryId.

Now, I want to reference at the same time now CityId and PostalCodeId, but they have diferents level (and Level table should not change, beacuse is a master).

What do you think is the best way to solve this problem? I thought 2 solutions:

1) Remove the Level column on Union table and control in backend the number of parameters that are filled. But if the numbers of columns (FK) in Union is increased, I need to control so much conditions. And maybe it will be inefficient.

2) Create another level with an Id that represent the "new level". I think is not the best solution because, in fact, I have only 3 real levels. The other is a mix of levels, and the master wouldn't be a master as such.

I don't know if have a better solution or, if it is not, what is the best way to carry this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here at all. Can you post the actual ddl for the table instead of pseudocode? Something seems a bit off here to me but I don't understand the problem well enough to help fix it.

Comment: calling a table UNION is a terrible idea.

Comment: Your tables are supposed to represent real "things" in the business/system you are modelling. Without intimate knowledge of that information, no one can safely offer suggestions. You have one guess - which may or may not be helpful. What can be said is that this appears to be the wrong approach. Start over. If you need help, discuss your model and what it represents and how it will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is about mixing concepts, so you're missing the A ( atomicity ) in the ACID specification for relational databases.

You should create a separate table for cities, postal codes and countries. If you want, as they are related, you can reference the city a postal code belongs to, and so the country the city belongs to also.

All Id fields are primary keys:

Level (Id, Name)

Country ( Id, level_id (fk), name )

City ( Id, level_id (fk), country_id (FK), name )

PostalCode ( Id, level_id (fk), city_id (FK), name )

You can add also the country_id inside the PostalCode table if it helps some searches, but it's redundant as you can get it with the FK city_id and the country_id inside.

Not sure if this helps to solve your question, please include some full example ( with sample data in each table ) if you need more information.

EDIT:
You can also structure a self-referencing table to do the same if it's better for you:

union_table

Id  level   country_id  city_id name

1     3          0       0      United Kingdom

2   2   0   0   London

3   1   2   2   YX-223

country_id references union_table.Id, and city_id references also union_table.Id. Then, level determines if it's postal code (1), city (2) or country (3). None of country_id nor city_id are foreign keys, but should be indexed.